# Xtext with rule ovewrite and grammar inheretance

Tags: parsing, xtext

I have a parent grammar:

```
grammar org.spr.mydsl.MySuperDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate mySuperDsl "http://www.spr.org/mydsl/MySuperDsl"
SuperModel:
    greetings+=Greeting*;   
Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID '!';
```

and a child grammar:

```
grammar org.lwr.MyLowerDsl with org.spr.mydsl.MySuperDsl
generate myLowerDsl "http://www.lwr.org/MyLowerDsl"
LowerModel:
    lower_greetings=LowerGreeting
    other_gretting=OtherGreeting
    super_greetings=Greeting
    refname=[CommonGreeting];   
LowerGreeting:
    'Lower Hello' name=ID '!';
OtherGreeting:
    'Other Hello' name=ID '!';  
CommonGreeting:
    LowerGreeting|OtherGreeting;
```

and the two grammar work. When the rule

```
CommonGreeting:
    LowerGreeting|Greeting|OtherGreeting;
```

is used instead the rule give an error and during execution of the mw work flow. The error is `Cannot add supertype 'CommonGreeting' to sealed type 'Greeting'. (ErrorCode: CannotCreateTypeInSealedMetamodel)`.

What do I need to do to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively you can import the super grammars metamodel and set the type of the `CommonGreeting` to the type of `Greeting`

e.g.

```
import "http://www.spr.org/mydsl/MySuperDsl" as superdsl

CommonGreeting returns superdsl::Greeting:
    LowerGreeting|OtherGreeting;
```

this makes `LowerGreeting` and `OtherGreeting` subtypes of `Greeting`

Comment: LowerGreeting|OtherGreeting can now also be used in the grammar MySuperDsl, can these rules be limited to extension created in grammar MyLowerDsl?

Comment: How do you mean ? As cross ref? You would have to filter inside the scooeprovider

Comment: Yes as cross ref.

Comment: Or you can define CommonGreeting as type in super

Comment: Uncalled rule `CommonGreeting:Greeting;`

Answer (score 1):

Is your question correct? `CommonGreeting` looks the same in both examples. I assume it should be `Greeting|LowerGreeting|OtherGreeting` in the first case.

Xtext infers 2 EMF models, one for the super grammar and one for the lower grammar. During inferring the second you are trying to change the first, like add a new supertype to the concept of the super grammar. The error says that this concept is already inferred and cannot be changed. 
You can overcome it by introducing `CommonGreeting` in the super grammar or by defining your own EMF model and using it both grammar instead of inferring.